# Why are many options missing from the editor?

Tags: editor

I want to say for the record that I'm extremely new to anything related to Wordpress.

So my editor looks like this:

[image: editor]

I see all sorts of screenshots and blog-posts everywhere that show a much much richer set of options in the editor. I can't set the font size / color, paragraphs, headings and much more. Why don't I have these options ?

I disabled every plugin -> nothing. I switched to a few other themes -> nothing.

It's very frustrating to having so few options for customizing how the blog text looks like.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't figure out what.

PS 1: I have Wordpress 4.4.2 installed manually on my webhosting account.

PS 2: Everything else works great.

Comment: Do you see Visual and Text tabs in the right-top corner of the editor? Just press the Visual tab. And please, in the future remember that this site is for questions about software development; this kind of questions is quite off-topic as they don't involve development issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your editor to use the visual mode instead of the text mode. You'll find this on the right-hand side of your editor. Also, see the item with a grey box around it in the below image. That's the "kitchen sink" button. It toggle's the rest of the toolbar for a deeper list of options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although it is a little weird to not see those options in "Text mode".